# qml webview gmail.com, others, not loading or incomplete

Tags: qt, qml

Im using a QML Webview.  It appears to work fine for sites like
intel.com, apple.com, cnn.com, foxnews.com, however if I try to
load gmail.com or hotmail.com, it appears to only load the following html:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
==== load finished
```

This gets dumped by a debug msg I have in the onLoadFinished event.

Here's how I setup my Webview:

```
WebView {
    id: webView
    focus: true
    preferredWidth: webkit.width
    preferredHeight: webkit.height
    settings.autoLoadImages: true
    settings.javascriptEnabled: true
    settings.javascriptCanOpenWindows: true
    settings.minimumFontSize: 12
    settings.defaultFontSize: webkit.fontsize
    url: ""

onLoadFinished: {
        console.debug(webView.html);
        console.debug("==== load finished");
}
}
```

(Other events not shown)

Anyone have an idea of what I might be doing wrong?
If Im missing a setting I dont know because there is so little
documentation on the 'settings' (unless its obvious).  We are using
4.7.1 however I did try 4.8.2 with same results.

Thanks

[EDIT] A coworker suggested that it may be a User-Agent issue.  Ive seen 
many articles on modifying that for the C++ version of QWebView but I dont see
how its possible to do from the QML side, unless I hack the Qt source directly.
Anyone think that may be the issue?  I would doubt it because gmail.com works
just fine in my other web browsers on my desktop (ubuntu 11.10)

[EDIT] I compiled the 'browser' example in Qt 4.7.1, it doesnt work there either.
Qt came out with 4.8.3 the other day and when I compiled 'browser' there, it (browser) worked.  I noticed that gmail.com changes from http: to https: so I thought maybe it was
because we were compiling QT with -no-openssl.  I tried compiling 4.7.1 AND 4.8.3
with openssl with no luck to my QML problem.

[SEMI-SOLVED] Turns out its poor QT documentation (for starters).  QML Webview doesnt
tell you in their docs that you need to install your own NetworkAccessManagerFactory.
DeclarativeView has an engine() (at least in 4.7.1) in which you call setNetworkAccessManagerFactory() with your own Factory.  Now that I did that, it works
on my Desktop, but not on our embedded linux device. although it doesnt 'lock up' downloading gmail.com at 10%, it just fails now.  I also had to compile Qt with openssl,
however it is loading my openssl libraries (ssl and crypto), but not working on the 
embedded device yet.  Very odd.

[SOLVED] Weird, but it seems that I did not implement QNetworkAccessManager::sslErrors(QNetworkReply *, QList))
signal.  This had no effect on the desktop, but when I went to the embedded device it
wouldnt work, now it does.